# ffmpeg not working in php shell_exec

Tags: 20.04, apache2, php, ffmpeg, xampp

I am new to ubuntu and currently working with apache on localhost.
I've recently installed `ffmpeg` using `sudo apt install ffmpeg`.
`ffmpeg` is working fine in terminal but when I use it in my php script I get the following output from `ffmpeg`:

```
/opt/lampstack-8.0.6-0/common/lib/libuuid.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1) ffmpeg: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates
```

I am using `ffmpeg` like below in my PHP script:

```
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg 2>&1');
```

Comment: Did you try to use the full path in the PHP script? See `whereis ffmpeg` output.

Comment: Yeah i also tried /usr/bin/ffmpeg

Comment: which ffmpeg also outputs /usr/bin/ffmpeg

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `ldd $(which ffmpeg)`, formatted as _code_, i.e. with a line consisting of 3 backticks ``` before and after. My ffmpeg loads libuuid from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1`; that path `/opt/lampstack-8.0.6-0/common/lib/libuuid.so.1` is suspicious. Do you have a custom `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your Apache2 setup so it tries to load shared libs from `/opt/lampstack...`?

Comment: adding ```export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"``` worked for me. Thanks For Your Reply Sir. Apache was Setting Up The $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. In my case, my problem were the directory's permissions, I mean, the directory where I wanted to save my video did not have the write permissions....that's all.